# Require highcharts-browserify to use specific version of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, browserify

I'm working with [highcharts-browserify](https://github.com/soldair/highcharts-browserify). This is what my package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch-index": "watchify index.js -o ../../static/js/index.js --debug --verbose",
    "watch": "npm run watch-index",
    "build-index": "browserify index.js | uglifyjs > ../../static/js/index.min.js",
    "build": "npm run build-index"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "highcharts-browserify": "^0.1.5-4.1.7",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
  }
}
```

However, when I run `npm run watch`, the compiled file has v4.0.4 of Highcharts in it, not the latest version (v4.1.7).

How can I make sure I've got the latest version?

I need to use the latest version because of this bug in x-axis labels in v4.0.4 of Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/5z8rf83y/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `highcharts-browserify` library currently uses v 4.0.4.

https://github.com/soldair/highcharts-browserify/blob/master/highcharts.js#L2

You could open a ticket to have it updated, or fix it and submit a pull request.

Also, you can by pass using this library, and use `browserify-shim` which would look like this -

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "Highcharts": {
      "depends": ["HighchartsAdapter:HighchartsAdapter"],
      "exports": "Highcharts"
    },
    "HighchartsAdapter": {"exports":"HighchartsAdapter"}
  },
  "browser": {
    "Highcharts": "./bower_components/highcharts-release/highcharts.src.js",
    "HighchartsAdapter": "./bower_components/highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.src.js"
  }
}
```